# How can I setblock of a button that is always pushed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a button that is always pushed for building purposes, how would I do this?

Comment: If you can tell us what you're trying to do, there might be other ways to do it as well!

Comment: You can accept answers that worked for you, even though it's a slightly alternative solution.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use the Debug Stick to alter the "state" of the button to be "powered". You can give yourself a Debug Stick with `/give @s debug_stick`. To learn more about block states, this page can help you https://minecraft.wiki/w/Block_states, and for the debug stick, this page: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Debug_Stick

Note that if the button is right clicked after you alter the block state with the Debug Stick it will go back to being unpowered, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Thank you this really helped me :)